# Unable to upload file (of any size) in SharePoint 2003 [Web Server busy error]

Tags: document-library, file-upload, 2003, wss-2.0

[image: screenshot]

While try to upload a file (any size) on any SharePoint 2003 document library, the browser is showing an error :  
**Form Validation Error** 
Please correct the information you provided by following these steps, then submit the information again:
    
Web server is busy. Please try again.

The sites are working fine. This issue occurs while uploading only.

DB properties show:
Space allocated for Data files= 3 MB
Space allocated for Transaction Log= 200MB.

Comment: Have you tried an IIS reset ?

Comment: Check the available disk space on the DB server.

Comment: @TempaC : Yes, done that too. But still getting the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your content database is full. This will show in the logs.

If not it will be one of the following:

- Site Collection Quota has been reached
- File type is disallowed
- SQL Server database size maximum reached
- SQL Server out of memory - restart server and plan an upgrade

Comment: Thanks for the help. I checked all the conditions, but the issue still persist -
1. Site Colln quota: More than 200 MB space left.
2. File type disallowed : No
3. SQL Server Database max size reached: No.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server Express? It has another restriction of 2GB per database

Comment: SQL Server is an enterprise edition.

Comment: Do you have any additional information from the logs? (SP/SQL/IIS logs) Has there been any recent database alterations? Have you tried restarting the servers?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Restarting the servers & SQL services resolved the issue. :)